# A defined custom variable in httpd.conf is detected as NULL in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, environment-variables, httpd.conf

So I want to have a different custom path for `.htaccess` in my machine and my live server. So that's why I am trying to create a custom variable in `httpd.conf` to be used in `.htaccess`. I wrote the variable like this at the very top of `httpd.conf`:

```
# Define a custom server base path for .htaccess RewriteBase
Define ServerBase "/PHP%20projects/sample"
```

And I access it from `.htaccess` like this:

```
<IfDefine ${ServerBase}>
    RewriteBase %{ServerBase}
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !${ServerBase}>
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfDefine>


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !vardump
RewriteRule (.*) https://sample.com/$1?vardump&base=%{ServerBase} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

I tried to debug it by trying to show it as a parameter in a URL from RewriteRule. It showed as NULL. What did I do wrong so it doesn't show the real value?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! I should have used the same host when I want to debug the server. I fixed it by fixing the `vardump` part in my `.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !vardump
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1?vardump&base=${ServerBase} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

And don't forget to clear your browser cache every time you debug.

It seems we should use `${ServerBase}` for a custom variable declared using `Define var_name var_value`. And we should use `%{HTTP_HOST}` for a default variable. Notice the `${}` and `%{}`.